# mysql select oop php

Tags: php, html, oop

This is my oop php code for connection for my database. But how can i do the `SELECT` function. i wanna show data in my page from database. help me with this

```
class createConnection //create a class for make connection
{
    var $host = "localhost";
    var $username = "root"; // specify the sever details for mysql
    var $password = "";
    var $database = "akpGroup";
    var $myconn;

    function connectToDatabase() // create a function for connect database
    {
        $conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);
        if (!$conn) // testing the connection
        {
            die ("Cannot connect to the database");
        } else {
            $this->myconn = $conn;
            echo "Connection established";
        }

        return $this->myconn;
    }

    function selectDatabase() // selecting the database.
    {
        mysql_select_db($this->database); //use php inbuild functions for select database
        if (mysql_error()) // if error occured display the error message
        {
            echo "Cannot find the database " . $this->database;
        }
        echo "Database selected..";
    }

    function closeConnection() // close the connection
    {
        mysql_close($this->myconn);
        echo "Connection closed";
    }
```

Comment: The select function? You mean the database or a query to select a table? Also, try to use `mysqli_*`, `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: yeahh I wanna select a table from the database. yeah its query to select a table.thanx noted

Comment: `OOP` and `mysql`, nice combination

Comment: I think you just need to add `$this->myconn` to your `mysql_select_db` function.

Comment: @putvande PDO is a superior choice over mysqli_*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like this

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','yourPassword')
mysql_select_db('database_name', $link);
$sql = 'SELECT column FROM tablename';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all consider using mylsqi_ or PDO functions.

Basically your function for querying should look something like the one below. It makes query and puts all the results into an array.

You can return the array or assign it to a class variable like you did in other methods.

```
  function query($sql) {
        $result_array = array();
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
              while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                    $result_array[] = $fetch;
              }
        }
        else {
              //no results action if needed
        }

        return $result_array;
  }
```

Comment: employee is the tabale. so can u please edit the code for it. Im new to this ... where should i put the query(Select * FROM employee). I wanna print it on my page..thank you

Comment: $db = new createConnection();
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM employee");